# Querying Kibana using grok pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok

We have configured ELK stack over our daily logs and using `Kibana` UI to perform basic search/query operation on the the set of logs.

Some of our logs have a certain field in the message while others don't. Therefore we have not configured it as a separate field while configuring `Logstash`.

I have logs like:

```
[28/Jun/2016:23:59:56 +0530] 192.168.xxx.xxx [API:Profile]get_data_login: Project password success:  9xxxxxxxxx0
[28/Jun/2016:23:59:56 +0530] 192.168.xxx.xxx [API:Profile]session_end: logout success:  9xxxxxxxxx0 TotalTime:1.1234
```

In these two logs, I wish to extract `TotalTime` for all `session_end` logs. And visualize it.

How should I do it?

I can search all the logs which are listed under `session_end`, however I am not able to perform grok on the set of logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your filter in logstash you can have something like :

```
filter {

    ...

    if ([message] ~= "session_end") {
        grok {
             #write grok specifically for the second format of log here
        }
    }
    else if ([message] ~= "get_data_login") {
        grok {
             #write grok specifically for the first format of log here
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

Grok patterns cannot be used for querying in Kibana.

Comment: It might be more efficient to do the filtering with positive comparison, like:  if ([message] ~= "session_end:" and [message] ~= "TotalTime:")

Answer (score 1):

You can use two different grok patterns in the same filter:

```
grok {
  match => {
    "message" => ['\[%{HTTPDATE}\] %{IP} \[API:Profile\]session_end: %{GREEDYDATA:session} TotalTime:%{GREEDYDATA:tt}',
                '\[%{HTTPDATE}\] %{IP} \[API:Profile\]%{GREEDYDATA:data}']
  }
}
```

The messages will be tested by the first pattern, if they have `session_end:` and `TotalTime:`, you'll have an elasticsearch document with the two fields. Then you'll be able to do aggregations and visualisation on these fields.

The other messages (without `session_end:` and `TotalTime:`) will be parsed by the second filter.